# How to reliably split the contents of a TextBox into lines?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, textbox, line-breaks

When I get `TextBox.Text`, how can I split it into lines?

For text files I do this by splitting at `\r\n` (Notepad++). With the `TextBox`, usually it is `\r\n`, but apparently not always - since my `\r\n` split occasionally fails for pasted input. Luckily for text files I can use Notepad++'s "Show all characters" features to inspect the whitespace. But how can I see what characters are in the `TextBox`?

Clearly the `TextBox` itself knows how to deal with this, since it is able to display the text with linebreaks at correct locations. How can I take `var s = MyTextBox.Text;` and "*split `s` at every location where the `TextBox` would have displayed a break*"?

**Edit:** I've checked my Regex and actually I am already splitting at `Environment.Newline`, not `\r\n`.

Comment: If you're using a RichTextBox, it literally has a property called "lines".

Comment: @Rariolu The standard TextBox has it, too.

Comment: interestingly TextBox.Lines doesn't use Environment.NewLine, it breaks line if it sees `\n` or `\r`. A user could be copying text from some source that was not created in windows

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
var lines = Regex.Split(s, @"\r\n|\r|\n");
```

to reliably split at any newline, no matter where the newlines came from.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a `TextBox`, you can use the `Lines` property, as suggested in the comments. But you might need to get the lines from a string in other situations too.

For doing this I use an extension method based on a `StringReader`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(this string s)
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

(this method is also available in my [NString library](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NString#getlines))

You can use it like this:

```
string[] lines = textBox.Text.GetLines().ToArray();
```

The `StringReader` class knows where to split the lines, and it's probably faster than using a regex (<strike>just an intuition, I haven't actually benchmarked it</strike> *EDIT: I just did a quick benchmark, `StringReader` is about 6 times faster than `Regex`*)